# About paypal mobile express ceckout : payment succeeds, but user can't receive result because of network error

Tags: networking, paypal, payment, checkout

For transactional payment, including Paypal.
     App will send payment information to Paypal server.
     And Paypal will return result for DoExpressCheckoutPayment.
     What if DoExpressCheckoutPayment return success, but 
     APP didn't receive this message ?
     How do you handle this problem ?
     In my experience, it happens for mobile phone in unstable networking environment for 
     other paypal-like payment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the transaction with actor the same data. PayPal should enforce idempotence of the transaction. If they don't, she them, they're a bank, they should know this stuff.